# dynamically allocated array of integers produces weird output after realloc() or (double free or corruption error)

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

size_t array_resize(int64_t **array, size_t array_size, size_t resize_num) {
    size_t new_size = array_size + resize_num;
    int64_t *temp = realloc(*array, sizeof(int64_t) * resize_num);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("failed realloc\n");
        free(array);
        exit(1);
    }
    *array = temp;
    free(temp);
    return new_size;
}

int main(void) {
    int array_size = 10;
    int64_t *array;
    array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int64_t));

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        printf("%li ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    array_size = array_resize(&array, array_size, 15);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        printf("%li ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

this code produces output as I had hoped for:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

but if I change the size by which I am making the array larger like this for example:

```
(...)
    array_size = array_resize(&array, array_size, 5);
(...)
```

the output changes to something I don't understand:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 2320515111958224945 2321641029045198901 2319689297389756473
```

another case that causes a problem is this:

```
(...)
array_size = array_resize(&array, array_size, 130);
(...)
```

and this is the output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 
double free or corruption (top)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have found several other combinations of initial array size and the size by which I am increasing the array which produces this behaviour. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You are freeing the newly allocated array:

> ```
>     *array = temp;
>     free(temp);
> ```

That completely defeats the apparent purpose of your `array_resize()` function.  When the function returns, the caller's pointer is invalid, the lifetime of the allocated object to which its value once pointed having ended even before the function returned.  You might as well skip the reallocation and error check, and just

```
    free(*array);
```

***Or*** remove the `free` call, instead.  This is more likely to give you behavior in line with your expectations.

> this code produces output as I had hoped for:

That is among the possible manifestations of the program's undefined behavior.

> but if I change the size by which I am making the array larger [...] the output changes to something I don't understand

That is also among the possible manifestation's of the program's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes in your `array_resize` function:

- you reallocate the block with `realloc(*array, sizeof(int64_t) * resize_num);` but you must pass the new size to `realloc`, not the increment. Therefore you should write:

  ```
      int64_t *temp = realloc(*array, sizeof(int64_t) * new_size);
  ```

  as coded, you are actually reducing the size, hence accessing data beyond the new reduced size has undefined behavior, and indeed some of the data appears corrupted, but undefined behavior could result in other side effects, including nothing visible.
- you free `array` in case of `realloc` failure, but you should instead free `*array`, the pointer to the original block.
- you free `temp` after storing its value to `*array`, effectively releasing the memory back to the system. Using this memory after the `free` has undefined behavior: its contents are indeterminate and may not even be accessible.  You should not free the memory pointed to by the `temp` pointer at all.

Here is a modified version:

```
size_t array_resize(int64_t **array, size_t array_size, size_t resize_num) {
    size_t new_size = array_size + resize_num;
    int64_t *temp = realloc(*array, sizeof(int64_t) * new_size);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("failed realloc\n");
        free(*array);
        exit(1);
    }
    *array = temp;
    return new_size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters to output values of the type `int64_t` you need to include header `<inttypes.h>` and to use macro `PRIi64` like:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

printf( "%" PRIi64 " ", array[i] );
```

instead of:

```
printf("%li ", array[i]);
```

where the conversion specification `li` is designed to output values of the type `long int`. It is not necessary that `sizeof( long int )` is equal to `sizeof( int64_t )`.

As for the function `array_resize` itself then it is incorrect.

Instead of this statement:

```
free(array);
```

you need to write:

```
free( *array );
```

dereferencing the pointer to the original pointer.

If memory was successfully reallocated using `realloc` then you shall not free the previous addressable extent of memory. That is this statement

```
free(temp);
```

frees the newly allocated memory. Remove it.

Another problem is that you allocate only `resize_num` elements while the function returns the value of `new_size`:

```
int64_t *temp = realloc( *array, sizeof( int64_t ) * resize_num );

//...

return new_size;
```

And the function should not issue any message. It is the caller of the function decides whether to issue a message in case of failure of reallocating the array.

The function can look the following way:

```
size_t array_resize( int64_t **array, size_t array_size, size_t resize_num ) 
{
    size_t new_size = array_size + resize_num;

    int64_t *temp = realloc( *array, sizeof( int64_t ) * new_size );

    if (temp == NULL) 
    {
        new_size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        *array = temp;
    }

    return new_size;
}
```

And in main you can write for example

```
size_t array_size = 10;
int64_t *array;
array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int64_t));

for ( size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++ ) 
{
    array[i] = i + 1;
}

for ( size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++ ) 
{
    printf( "%" PRIi64 " ", array[i] );
}
putchar( '\n' );

size_t new_array_size = array_resize( &array, array_size, 15 );

if ( !new_array_size )
{
    puts( "failed realloc" );
}
else
{
    array_size = new_array_size;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++ ) 
    {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%" PRIi64 " ", array[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

free( array );

// ...
```

And use the type `size_t` everywhere in the program instead of the type `int` for  the size of the array and indices to access elements of the array.

It is also desirable to check whether the first using of `malloc` in `main` was successful.

Pay attention to that the function `realloc` preserves values of  elements of an array that fit in the new reallocated array.

So you could rewrite this for loop:

```
    array_size = new_array_size;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++ ) 
    {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
```

the following way:

```
    for ( size_t i = array_size; i < new_array_size; i++ ) 
    {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }

    array_size = new_array_size;
```

Answer (score 1):

C17 ISO draft says about realloc at 7.22.3.5

```
#include <stdlib.h>
    void*
    realloc(void* ptr, size_t size);
```

- 2 The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a pointer to a new
  object that has the size specified by size. The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of
  the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new
  object beyond the size of the old object have indeterminate values.
- 3 If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the specified size.
  Otherwise, if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if
  the space has been deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function, the behavior is undefined.
  If size is nonzero and memory for the new object is not allocated, the old object is not deallocated.
  If size is zero and memory for the new object is not allocated, it is implementation-defined whether
  the old object is deallocated. If the old object is not deallocated, its value shall be unchanged.
- Returns

  - 4 The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a
    pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object has not been allocated.

C11 says the same.

So in

```
size_t array_resize(
    int64_t** array, size_t array_size, size_t resize_num)
{
    size_t   new_size = array_size + resize_num;
    int64_t* temp =
        realloc(*array, sizeof(int64_t) * resize_num);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed realloc\n");
        free(array);
        exit(1);
    }
    *array = temp;
    free(temp);
    return new_size;
}
```

**you can not free anything here**. The original area may be already deallocated, and to free the newly allocated would make no sense. Just delete that call to `free()`.

#### naming

just in the first 3 lines of `array_resize()` the word  *size* appears 10 times. And I was never sure about what is what. `new_size` is the size in `int64_t` elements but could be bytes. The `resize_num` could be a difference in size, or a total in bytes or a total in `int64_t` elements. Maybe you could consider another naming strategy.

#### could use a new abstraction

You may find useful a new `Array` struct like

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t   size; // array size
    int64_t* array;
} Array;
```

and

```
Array* array_create(size_t);
int    array_display(Array*, const char*);
Array* array_resize(Array*, size_t);
Array* array_free(Array*);
```

So in use you could write

```
int main(void)
{
    Array* t_arr = array_create(4);
    array_display(t_arr, "4 before resize to 8");
    t_arr = array_resize(t_arr, 8);
    array_display(t_arr, "8 before resize to 2");
    t_arr = array_resize(t_arr, 2);
    array_display(t_arr, "2 values, before array_free()");
    t_arr = array_free(t_arr);
    array_display(
        t_arr, "after array_free()");
    return 0;
}
```

and see, for the code in the example

```
4 before resize to 8

    array size is: 4
    [ 0 1 2 3 ]

8 before resize to 2

    array size is: 8
    [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]

2 values, before array_free()

    array size is: 2
    [ 0 1 ]

    array not allocated
```

As we see in other languages, encapsulation makes the code easier to read and manage.

### complete `C` example

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t   size;
    int64_t* array;
} Array;

Array* array_create(size_t);
int    array_display(Array*, const char*);
Array* array_resize(Array*, size_t);
Array* array_free(Array*);

int main(void)
{
    Array* t_arr = array_create(4);
    array_display(t_arr, "4 before resize to 8");
    t_arr = array_resize(t_arr, 8);
    array_display(t_arr, "8 before resize to 2");
    t_arr = array_resize(t_arr, 2);
    array_display(t_arr, "2 values, before array_free()");
    t_arr = array_free(t_arr);
    array_display(
        t_arr, "after array_free()");
    return 0;
}

Array* array_create(size_t size)
{
    Array* one = (Array*)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->size  = size;
    one->array = (int64_t*)malloc(sizeof(int64_t) * size);
    if (one->array == NULL)
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    // for testing: number all elements
    for (size_t i = 0; i < one->size; i++)
        one->array[i] = i;
    return one;
}

int array_display(Array* blk, const char* msg)
{
    if (blk == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "    array not allocated\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("\n\n    array size is: %llu\n    [ ", blk->size);
    for (int i = 0; i < blk->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%lli ", blk->array[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n\n");
    return 0;
}

Array* array_resize(Array* orig, size_t size)
{
    if (orig == NULL) return NULL;
    int64_t* new_arr =
        realloc(orig->array, sizeof(uint64_t) * size);
    if (new_arr == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "    realloc() failed\n");
    else
    {
        orig->array = new_arr;
        orig->size  = size;
        // for testing: number all elements
        for (size_t i = 0; i < orig->size; i++)
            orig->array[i] = i;
    }
    return orig;
}

Array* array_free(Array* blk)
{
    if (blk == NULL) return NULL;
    free(blk->array);
    free(blk);
    return NULL;
}
```